# Looping through element's ids in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few div elements with ids in my html.

This is my js:

```
var frameList =  $('div');

for(i = 0; i < frameList.length; i++) {
    console.log(frameList[i].attr('id'));
};
```

That is, I am getting the list of elements, then looping over each element and trying to get its id. This is not working and I understand why. How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically collections of elements that match a jQuery selector are iterated using each, where `this` is bound to the current element of the matched set during iteration

```
$('div').each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

With your specific example though...

The problem here is that when you access the `frameList` using array indices, you are accessing the psuedo array that jQuery creates. This underlying array merely holds the set of elements that matched the selector or were contained in the jQuery object.

These elements only expose the native API. One option here would be to access the native id on these elements.

```
console.log(frameList[i].id);
```

Another option would be to use the jQuery function `eq` to get the jQuery object for that element and then use `attr`

```
console.log(frameList.eq(i).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`frameList[i]` is not a jQuery object so `.attr()` is not defined.

Either `frameList[i].id` or `frameList.eq(i).attr("id")`  should work though:

```js
var frameList = $('div');

for(i = 0; i < frameList.length; i++) {
  console.log(frameList[i].id);
  console.log(frameList.eq(i).attr("id"));
};
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

Comment: using `.attr('id')` is a jQuery code smell

Answer (score 1):

Now that you are using jQuery you should use jQuery.each:

```
$('div').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: thank you but is this question really a duplicate of the other one?

Comment: @jgozal Your problem is the exact the same as OP's in the other question. The solution I provided is another solution to your problem, if anything you should accept TravisJ's answer as the answer to your question. He atleast try to explain what is happening :-)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I appreciate all the other answers and sometimes wish I could approve all of them. But I did say in my question that I understood why my code wasn't working so there was no need of explanation, and I thought your solution was the simplest and most elegant as it avoids creating new variable.